# is it possible to play one vibration for less than 0.25 second in ios in objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i need to play vibration in ios for less than 0.25 second and the sequence of vibration will be like

1 vibration for 0.25 sec then 3 vibration for 0.15 second and this loop will continue for limited time say 2 or 3 minute. also the accuracy is needed here means each vibration must have to start at exact time

right now when i play vibration it play exactly one time per second

```
-(IBAction)onBtnVibrateClicked:(id)sender {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

    [myTimer invalidate];
    if(_txt_VibrationPerMinute.text.length == 0){
        _txt_VibrationPerMinute.text = @"10";
    }
    myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60/[_txt_VibrationPerMinute.text intValue]
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(targetMethod:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)obBtnStopVibrationClicked:(id)sender {

    [myTimer invalidate];


}

-(void)targetMethod:(NSTimer *)timer {
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
}
```

Comment: According to [this](http://www.kimballlarsen.com/2009/12/22/how-to-make-iphone-vibrate-for-a-long-time/), `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)` produces a vibration of 0.4 seconds, so I don't think it's possible to create a vibration for a shorter period than that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use something like this

```
FOUNDATION_EXTERN void AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(UInt32 inSystemSoundID,id arg,NSDictionary* vibratePattern);

void vibrate(float durationInSeconds, float intensivity, long count)
{
    NSMutableDictionary* dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSMutableArray* arr = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (long i = count; i--;)
    {
        [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]]; //vibrate
        [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:durationInSeconds*1000]];

        [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];  //stop
        [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:durationInSeconds*1000]];
    }

    [dict setObject:arr forKey:@"VibePattern"];
    [dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:intensivity] forKey:@"Intensity"];

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSoundWithVibration(4095,nil,dict);
}
```